# How to write a function that puts operators between numbers?

Tags: python, math, solver

How can I write a programme, that
Receives:
1 2 4 = 7
Outputs:
1 + 2 + 4 = 7

So I need to write a programme, that will put operators between numbers to get right answer.

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this solves your given problem and similar cases. There would be a lot of conditions to check. This assumes operator precedence has to be considered, but you can also use it for simple running results (like in some of the Brilliant daily problems). The operator choice is quick and dirty and can be improved upon, also exhaustive testing would be needed to cover more complex cases. This is only to illustrate one simple approach:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations_with_replacement

def clclin(coeffl, rslt, copl):
    '''simple forward solve'''
    if len(coeffl)!=len(copl)+1:
        return False
    cv = coeffl[0]
    for icf in range(len(copl)):
        if copl[icf]=='+':
            cv += coeffl[icf+1]
        elif copl[icf]=='-':
            cv -= coeffl[icf+1]
        elif copl[icf]=='*':
            cv *= coeffl[icf+1]
        elif copl[icf]=='/' and coeffl[icf+1]!=0:
            cv /= coeffl[icf+1]
        else:
            return False
    return cv==rslt

def clcop(coeffl, rslt, copl):
    '''consider precedence'''
    if len(coeffl)!=len(copl)+1:
        return False
    cv = [coeffl[0]]
    co = []
    for icf in range(len(copl)):
        if copl[icf]=='*':
            cv[-1] *= coeffl[icf+1]
        elif copl[icf]=='/':
            if coeffl[icf+1]!=0:
                cv[-1] /= coeffl[icf+1]
            else:
                return False
        else:
            cv.append(coeffl[icf+1])
            co.append(copl[icf])
    return clclin(cv, rslt, co)

def solvop(coeffl, rslt, vldop='+-*/'):
    '''try to solve coefficients combined via valid operators for given result'''
    if len(coeffl)==0: # only rudimentary error handling
        return []
    pcopl = []
    for p in combinations_with_replacement(vldop, len(coeffl)-1): # sloppily building all operator lists (can be improved)
        for el in permutations(p, len(coeffl)-1):
            pcopl.append(el)
    for copl in pcopl:
        if clcop(coeffl, rslt, copl): # use clclin for simple linear calculation w/o operator precedence
            return copl
    return []

print(list(solvop([1,2,4], 7)))
print(list(solvop([1,3,4], 7)))
print(list(solvop([1,2,4], 8)))
print(list(solvop([1,2,4], 1/8)))
print(list(solvop([1,2,0], 1/8)))
print(list(solvop([], 1/8)))
print(list(solvop([1,2,3], 7)))
print(list(solvop([1,2,0], 2)))
print(list(solvop([1,2,0,0,0,0], 2)))
print(list(solvop([0,0,0,0,2,0], 2)))
print(list(solvop([0,0,0,0,2,0], 5)))
print(list(solvop([0,0,0,0,-2,-1], 2)))
```

which produces (1st line is your question):

```
['+', '+']
['*', '+']
['*', '*']
['/', '/']
[]
[]
['+', '*']
['*', '+']
['*', '+', '+', '+', '+']
['+', '+', '+', '+', '+']
[]
['+', '+', '+', '+', '*']
```